# Debit cards & direct deposit?

Tags: debitcard

If I wanted to close my bank account and perhaps set up a direct deposit through my employer, is that possible?

Also, will there or are there any Bitcoin debit cards?

I am still trying to understand this.

Comment: If you close your bank account, where would your money be direct deposited *to*?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to ask your employer, but I have never seen that before.

For bitcoin debit cards read this:

http://www.engadget.com/2012/08/20/bitinstant-founder-says-bitcoin-debit-card-to-launch-within-next/

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, and your employer may be weird)*

Not really. Bitcoin isn't directly related with any bank, so where to directly deposit would be the biggest question.

You could use [Coinbase](https://coinbase.com), which makes it stupidly easy to buy bitcoins with any US bank account for a very small fee. If you're in Europe, I would recommend [Bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net), which supports SEPA transfers from any bank that supports it (like most European banks).

Another option would be to have your employer give you cash and you can directly trade that with a local trader from a site like [Local Bitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com).

However, as great as bitcoin is, I would recommend continuing to get your payments in USD and converting to bitcoin when you need to pay, instead of the other way around.